# CSS Media Queries working in Dolphin browser but not Chrome or Safari?

Tags: css, media-queries

I've done a lot of reading off of stackoverflow and various sites off of google, but I haven't been able to find a solution for this yet. :(

I have in my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mobile-style.css" />
```

(I originally only had the first two in my meta viewport content (width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0), but added the second two after reading through some articles.)

In my `mobile-style.css` file, I have:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 568px;) {
  ...
}
```

I have experimented with the max-device-width here as well, it has been 320, 480, 600, and 680... none of them work.

I can view this mobile stylesheet on my xperia Z using the dolphin browser (but not the Chrome browser), and on my friend's iPhone 3GS.  Elsewhere it doesn't show up.  The goal is just a simple mobile layout for the current site for any smaller-sized screen device.

Let me know if I should be providing more information.

Thanks! :)

**EDIT**

Here is the gist for my mobile-style.css file: https://gist.github.com/melissanoelle/7043032

Sorry for the delay, I've been away from a computer while traveling for my grandfather's funeral. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to change my css query to this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px), screen and (max-device-width: 568px) {
...
}
```

I got rid of the semi-colons and created a query for both `max-width` and `max-device-width`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 480px) { /* change to your breakpoint */
 ...
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I don't get why it would work in Dolphin browser but not in Chrome.  I'm finding it a little strange.

Answer (score 0):

Do you find any difference once you change your media query from:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 568px;) {
  ...
}
```

To

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 568px) {
  ...
}
```

Are you sure you want to use max-device-width and not the max-width (targeted display area)?

Comment: No difference between `max-device-width` and `max-width`.  No difference when I switch from `@media only screen`, `@media screen`, or `@media all`. :(

Comment: Please share your css file: mobile-style.css

Comment: I have added the link to the gist in the original question as an edit.  Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Change your viewport to this:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
```

Do you still have issues?

Comment: What is it that you think I should change my viewport to?

Comment: Sorry. This is the recommended setting when dealing with responsive design.